# Generate warning on unlinked section

Tags: c++, c, linker, linker-scripts

I am writing my own linker script and startup code (for an embedded processor) and I am using the gnu linker.

At first, I started only supporting `C` code and I got my startup code working fine.....then I tried to link a `C++` program.  It linked and all was well, but it did not work.

After some debugging, I found out that the linker script did not put the `.sbss` section anywhere (I did put the `.bss` section somewhere, but not the `.sbss`).  So here is my question:

Is it possible to generate a warning whenever a section is not linked to the program?.... A google search finds nothing and I browsed through the linker's manual but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to generate a warning whenever a section is not linked to the program?

I don't believe that's possible in the linker, but you can trivially implement it in a post-link step:

```
readelf -WS a.out | grep -q ' \.sbss' || { echo "Did not find .sbss!" >&2; false; }
```

> I want this to work for arbitrary sections (that I may not know about at this time)

Such warning would be useless, because it will fire *all the time*.

Consider:

- `main.o` defines `main` and doesn't reference anything else.
- `foo.o` defines `foo` and has sections `.x`, `.y` and `.z`. `foo.o` is part of `libfoo.a`

Now, when you link with `gcc main.o -lfoo`, `foo.o` will *not* be pulled into the link (because there are no references to it), and your warning will now tell you that `.x`, `.y` and `.z` are not linked into the program.

Comment: Yes but I want this to work for arbitrary sections (that I may not know about at this time)